# APC UPS Powerchute | "The installer is unable to locate an APC battery"

Tags: windows, apc

Under Windows 10, I connected an APC UPS via USB. In case of a power failure, the servers are shut down by a script.

[image]

Installing the APC Powerchute I get the error message `The installer is unable to locate an APC battery ...`. The software can not be installed. The recommended troubleshooting does not show any abnormalities.

- The UPS is shown in the device manager
- Using [USBDeview by nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) (which is recommended by APC to troubleshoot this problems), does not show any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of `Powerchute`. The `Personal Edition` and the `Business Edition`. The personal Edition does not recognize the professional UPS.

Download and use the [Powerchute Business Edition](https://www.schneider-electric.com.hk/en/product-range-download/61932-powerchute-business-edition).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable the **Power** service from Services and then restart your computer.

After doing this it allowed me to successfully install the software.

Comment: It won't let me disable it.